# Using sed to input a grub MD5 bootloader password

Tags: sed, passwords, md5, bootloader, grub

I am having issues using sed injecting a password into the grub.conf file.

Here is the syntax I am using:

```
sed -i /^timeout/s/$/"\npassword -md5 $1$ctuLL1$V4DZinO.4eTYjsGXOfU1F/" /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Grub MD5:

> $1$ctuLL1$V4DZinO.4eTYjsGXOfU1F/

Thanks for looking!

Comment: What issues exactly? what error message are you getting?

Comment: Well, sed doesnt pass the whole MD5 into the grub.conf file. There are bits missing like the $ / and .

Answer (score 0):

What I used seems to be working:

```
sed -i -e 's/timeout=5/timeout=0\'$'\npassword --md5 blah/g' /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

It is how I'm injecting a password during cobbler provisioning.

Obviously, you'll have to escape any special characters in the MD5 hash otherwise `sed` will complain.